# Javascript sandbox iframe catch redirect URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page that uses an iframe from another domain. Due to security reasons, browsers cannot allow you to access contentDocument of the iframe. Which is good. **However, after adding sandbox attr to the iframe to prevent parent page redirection, is there a way to detect iframe attempts to change the window.top.location and catch the url for further processing?** This is because, the iframe does a process which when done, redirects to a confirmation page.

Comment: No, of course not. The Same Origin Policy still applies, and it dictates that this must not be possible.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the confirmation @CBroe